# Strange robots.txt problem in Apache nutch 1.17

Tags: nutch

I am having an strange problem with robots.txt when using nutch 1.17. I am using selenium protocol. Tried both firefox and chrome. The logs shows that robots.txt file cannot be parsed.

```
2020-09-14 08:15:45,751 WARN  robots.SimpleRobotRulesParser - Problem processing robots.txt for https://website.com/some.html
2020-09-14 08:15:45,751 WARN  robots.SimpleRobotRulesParser -    Unknown line in robots.txt file (size 156): ^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^K-N-�MLO�+�R�MM�L,H,*�K-*�u��O�I�r�,N���/��r.J,��MI�I��R02��
2020-09-14 08:15:45,752 WARN  robots.SimpleRobotRulesParser -    Unknown line in robots.txt file (size 156): E�^KQ��_B�������
2020-09-14 08:15:45,753 WARN  robots.SimpleRobotRulesParser -    Unknown line in robots.txt file (size 156): �j�Ss�J�3��MU���F7�^Q����<��T���^�FI��I/J,H-������5^B�[�p^E��^A^W^@^Z�`X�
```

I checked into robots.txt everythings fine.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /var/
Disallow: /path/
```

I don't know what's going on underneath nutch. But seems like nutch is trying to parse html page, instead of going via robots.txt of that particular domain. Does anyone knows about this issue?

Comment: I have seen a lot of issues related to SimpleRobotRulesParser .... after doing a lot of debugging i found few cases where this exception occur. 1) websites have some junk characters in robots.txt and unparsable lines 2) websites does not follow standard rules in writing robots.txt files.... can you please verify the http response ***charset*** type for robots.txt. and please also check is there any invisible characters in response text.

Comment: Hey @kavetiraviteja, just checked what you suggested. Everything is fine. content type is text/plain. Charset is UTF-8. Checked every letters there no weird characters found. It was working when I was using just http protocol. And I just confirmed this now as well. The problem starts when I start using selenium protocol.

Comment: it seems like issues in underlying http Response handlers ... i have checked HttpRobotRulesParser code (lib-http) ... this particular line uses ***Response response = ((HttpBase) http).getResponse(robotsUrl,
            new CrawlDatum(), false);*** uses underlying selenium request handler

Comment: and in protocol-interactiveselenium HttpResponse.java ***readPlainContent menthod*** is used ... because you verified content-type is text/plain

Comment: what is ***interactiveselenium.handlers*** in your nutch-site.xml?

Comment: I am not sure if I am using interactiveselenium handler. I haven't configured it yet because I don't think i need interactive selenium. I just want dynamic pages to render which doesn't need any interaction. Looking at nutch-default.xml. It's configured as DefaultHandler.

Comment: can you please provide plugin-includes conf from nutch-site.xml

Comment: "protocol-selenium|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor|image)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|indexer-elastic|extractor|indexfilter-waste|pagefilter-content" - The last few plugins are custom that I have created and testing... Those are just index filters...

Comment: Hey @kavetiraviteja, just wanted to let you know. I didn't tested thoroughly what was going wrong. I was getting these weird data as a response from socket connection. The socket connection and making a get request to robots.text was fine. Was just getting these weird data. For now did a quick fix by copying HttpResonce code from lib-http to lib-selenim. Everything is good so far.

Comment: I suspected a bug in HttpResponce class in protocol-selenium plugin. you can raise an issue in nutch (https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NUTCH/issues/NUTCH-1858?filter=allopenissues)... I'm glad to know about the status thank you!.